# Auto Scroll Jquery does not work on mobile

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this code that does horizontal autoscroll, I use it to show some images in a slider that I place horizontally.

Here is an example of the code.

The code works perfectly on desktop (PC) but when I use it on cell phones it doesn't work. It stays stuck and the scroll does not move.

What is the problem?

```js
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
    var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
    $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth },
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function () {
            targetElement.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
```

```css
#q1 { white-space: nowrap; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="q1">((BEGIN)) Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me Watch me ((END))</div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you use jQuery 1.7 and not a recent version of jQuery?

Comment: There is no reason, but also the poor thing with a recent version of jQuery